# Vuejs v-runtime-template dynamic load template render problem

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js

I develop aspnet core project.  I am using Vuejs, vuetift and v-runtime-template. When I bind to dynamic vuetify companent(v-select) to vruntime template COmbobox not working stable css. How can I solve this problem

My sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/52046684yl

v-runtime-template project github: https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem another companent with vue-dynamic. v-runtime-template project owner dont support this problem.

https://github.com/JounQin/vue-dynamic